# latitude error when converting ESPG:3857 to ESPG:4326 with proj4js

Tags: node.js, gis, proj4js

After rewriting my Ruby coordinate conversion code to Node.js with Proj4js I'm always getting the same error of 0.17876359947293707 in latitude:

```
var proj4 = require('proj4js');
function(pair) {
   var firstProjection = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +units=m +k=1.0 +nadgrids=@null +no_defs"
   var secondProjection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
   return proj4(firstProjection, secondProjection, pair);
 }([4156404,7480076.5]) 

[ 37.33761240175516, 55.7832340897427 ]
```

Ruby code gives me [37.33761240175515, 55.60447049026976] which is same as http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/ with projection strings from above.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for secondProjection:

```
+proj=longlat +a=6378137.0 +b=6356752.31424518 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=degrees
```

This is the predefined value in Proj4js.defs["EPSG:4326"]